# Show that $\frac{2n\bar{X}}{\beta} \sim \chi^2_{2n}$.

Tags: probability

Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be a random sample size from the following distribution $f_X(x) = \frac1{\beta}e^{-x\beta}$ for $x \in[0, \infty]$. Show that $\frac{2n\bar{X}}{\beta} \sim \chi^2_{2n}$.

First of all, I found that mgf of $X_i$, $m_{X_i}(t)$, is $\frac1{\beta^2-2t}$ for $t>\beta$. I also have that $m_{\frac{2n\bar{X}}{\beta}}(t) = (\frac1{\beta^2-2t})^n$. However, mgf of $\chi^2_{2n}$ should be $(\frac1{1-2t})^n$. So, I guess that this approach is wrong. I think that this is because there is no assumption that $X_i$ is independent. In this case, how should I solve this question?

Comment: How did you get $M_X(t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these sorts of questions the $X_i$ are usually independent, so you're on the right track. If $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\beta}e^{-x\beta}$, then it is $Gamma(1,\frac{1}{\beta})$, (also you can call it an exponential). Wikipedia gives the MGF of this as $(1-t\beta)^{-1}$ for $t>\beta$.

Calling $S=\frac{2n\bar{X}}{\beta}$, $M_S(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{\frac{2n}{\beta}t\bar{X}}] = M_X(\frac{2}{\beta}t)^n = (1-2t)^{-n}$.

Comment: Is it exponential? I thought that $f_X(x) = \frac1{\beta}e^{\frac{-x}{\beta}}$ has an exponential distribution with a parameter $\beta$...

Comment: yeah sure gamma is just a generalised exponential so with certain parameters is equivalent

Comment: Oh, I get it. Cheers!